# Can I read iBeacon data using AS3/Air?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, ibeacon

I am wanting to develop a simple micro location app using iBeacons (just arrived today...how exciting). I have zero experience coding native in iOS and Android however have developed several apps using AS3/Air so I was wondering if there is a way to receive the beacon data using AS3?

I know there is a Bluetooth ANE for Android (which is not production ready) but was hoping someone knew of an iOS and Android ANE.

Happy to pay someone to create one for me if possible!

Comment: As a long time AS2&3 developer, I can tell you that Objective C is simpler and easier to learn than you might think. Flash was great, but Xcode is a more pleasant environment to stick with, besides it will give you direct access to everything you want. Start learning it today and don't forget to say thanks later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, nobody has built a ANE wrapper for the [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/) or for the iOS CoreLocaton APIs.  There is an [iOS wrapper](http://blog.xamarin.com/apple-stores-use-ibeacons-and-so-can-you/) and an [Android wrapper for Xamarin](http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin-android-ibeacon-service) (another cross-platform development framework), and I have been approached by folks interested in building an Android wrapper for the [Basic4Android](http://www.basic4ppc.com/).

An ANE wrapper would be an interesting addition, so if anyone experienced with building them is interested in working on this, I would be happy to help on either the Android or iOS side.

Full disclosure:  I am the primary author of the Android iBeacon Library.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for clarifying. Hopefully some amazing developer sees benefit in developing such an ANE.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found iBeacon ANE on this site http://www.caffaware.com/archives/469
Good job! ;-)

Comment: That is wicked! Good find

Answer (score 1):

If anybody is still looking, a free ANE can be found here:
http://www.as3gamegears.com/air-native-extension/ibeacon/